# HLOOKUP() to look up ONE row only. No header

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a look up table in another sheet, for a room booking system. The "ROOMS" table is simple an X-Y row with a header:

[image]

In the main data sheet, I want to look up the rooms, but highlight RED/YELLOW rooms that have already been "booked" on the same row, as another room reference.

Here we have a normal booking where both rooms are different. That's acceptable:

[image]

But here we have the same room booking on both and they are highlighted RED:

[image]

This works because I have a Conditional Format on every Room Allocation cell like this:

```
=OR(I2=K2,I2=Q2,I2=T2,I2=W2,I2=Z22,I2=AF2,I2=AI2,I2=AP2,I2=AS2,I2=AV2,I2=AY2,I2=BB2,I2=BE2,I2=BK2,I2=BN2,I2=BQ2,I2=BT2) 
=OR(K2=I2,K2=Q2,K2=T2,K2=W2,K2=Z22,K2=AF2,K2=AK2,K2=AP2,K2=AS2,K2=AV2,K2=AY2,K2=BB2,K2=BE2,K2=BK2,K2=BN2,K2=BQ2,K2=BT2)
```

etc.

What I want to know, is there a way to do this using HLOOKUP on ONE row?

The reason I ask about the "one row" situation is that according to [this](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Hlookup-Function.html), the **table array** has to be a genuine table with a header and at least one row of data.

But as you can see above, I only have ONE row to work with, which is data only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could use a COUNTIF on that:

=COUNTIF($2:$2,A$2)>1

Note the absolute references.  That should work across all of row 2, but you can tweak it a bit if you want it to only apply to certain columns.

Comment: Sweet! Worked like a charm. Thank you

Comment: Any suggestion on how to replicate this over hundreds of rows? And I assume a way to get the row number dynamically, instead of it being locked to row 2?

Comment: Sure, just take off the dollar signs.

Highlight the range ($2:$[some arbitrarily high number]), then conditional format -> New Rule, and use the same formula without dollar signs, so:
=CountIf(2:2,A2)>1

Comment: Excellent! One more question, why A2? My criteria is to match the existing cell value with the same cell value anywhere in the same row. How does A2 achieve this?

Comment: Conditional formatting via formula is just like writing a formula in the cell and using the "fill across"/"fill down" tool.  The conditional formatting evaluates each cell number as it goes across the row and down the columns.  To understand better, try this experiment: enter the formula with A1 or B2; the highlights will shift over one cell.

Comment: Oh, and I used A2 specifically because I assume the range you are formatting is the full rows of 2:whatever.  If you were going to format a small table like C6:G15, for example, you'd use =CountIf(6:6,C6)>2 instead.  Excel will work itself across and down the range, and dynamically increment the formula for the formatting as it goes.